# System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Type Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.ITypeBase.get_ClrType()'

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core, .net-5, aspnetboilerplate

```
Good Day Developers,
Please I updated my .Net5 to .Net6 and I have this errors on adding migration:
```

System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Type Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.ITypeBase.get_ClrType()'.
at Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.AbpDbContext.OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
at Abp.Zero.EntityFrameworkCore.AbpZeroCommonDbContext`3.OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) at Abp.Zero.EntityFrameworkCore.AbpZeroDbContext`4.OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelCustomizer.Customize(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, DbContext context)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, ModelDependencies modelDependencies)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.GetModel(DbContext context, ModelCreationDependencies modelCreationDependencies, Boolean designTime)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel(Boolean designTime)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.<>c.b__8_4(IServiceProvider p)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCacMicrosoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.ITypeBase.get_ClrType()'.

**I have check all my microsoft.entityFrameworkcore packages and they are of the same version.**
Is pointing this version of my code,

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<BinaryObject>(b =>
            {
                b.HasIndex(e => new { e.TenantId });
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<ChatMessage>(b =>
            {
                b.HasIndex(e => new { e.TenantId, e.UserId, e.ReadState });
                b.HasIndex(e => new { e.TenantId, e.TargetUserId, e.ReadState });
                b.HasIndex(e => new { e.TargetTenantId, e.TargetUserId, e.ReadState });
                b.HasIndex(e => new { e.TargetTenantId, e.UserId, e.ReadState });
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Friendship>(b =>
            {
                b.HasIndex(e => new { e.TenantId, e.UserId });
                b.HasIndex(e => new { e.TenantId, e.FriendUserId });
                b.HasIndex(e => new { e.FriendTenantId, e.UserId });
                b.HasIndex(e => new { e.FriendTenantId, e.FriendUserId });
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Tenant>(b =>
            {
                b.HasIndex(e => new { e.SubscriptionEndDateUtc });
                b.HasIndex(e => new { e.CreationTime });
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<SubscriptionPayment>(b =>
            {
                b.HasIndex(e => new { e.Status, e.CreationTime });
                b.HasIndex(e => new { PaymentId = e.ExternalPaymentId, e.Gateway });
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<SubscriptionPaymentExtensionData>(b =>
            {
                b.HasQueryFilter(m => !m.IsDeleted)
                    .HasIndex(e => new { e.SubscriptionPaymentId, e.Key, e.IsDeleted })
                    .IsUnique();
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<UserDelegation>(b =>
            {
                b.HasIndex(e => new { e.TenantId, e.SourceUserId });
                b.HasIndex(e => new { e.TenantId, e.TargetUserId });
            });

            modelBuilder.ConfigurePersistedGrantEntity();
        }
```

Is there thing I can Implement to solve this issue.
**Please I need help**.

Answer (score 16):

This error occurs when you have different versions of `EntityFrameworkCore` and `NetCore` in your project, please be sure to install the version of `EntityFramework` compatible with your `NetCore` version.

For `NET 5.0` the packages are:

`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design [5.0.10]`
`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer [5.0.10]`
`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools [5.0.10]`

For `NET 6.0` you can install:

`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design [6.0.10]` 
`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer [6.0.10]` 
`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools [6.0.10]`

Comment: I'm upgrading from 6.0 to 7.0 and ran into this issue. Make sure in addition to this you also upgrade the `EFCore.NamingConventions` package if you're using it :)

Comment: Also got this error when I forgot to update Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EFCore when I went from 6 to 7.

Comment: OK. Well, I'm in the situation where I'm having to maintian cross-project integration tests which are failing as only half the company has had time to upgrade to .NET 8. The tests are now disabled, which is seems as a high-risk/high-impact liability. So how would one use EFCore N-1 for one half (arrangement) of the integration test and EFCore N for the other (assert) half?

Answer (score 0):

If you have only updated your EntityFrameworkCore nuget versions, you may encounter such an error.

**Some of your nuget packages may have an old EntityFrameworkCore version**.

*Make sure that all your nuget packages are up to date.*

For example, I upgraded my project and EntityFrameworkCore versions to version 8. The EntityFrameworkCore.EncryptColumn package was out of date and I was encountering this error. I got rid of this error with the preview version of the package.